# Nginx: client certificate authentication works with self-generated but doesn't with an "official"

Tags: certificate, nginx

after hours or research, I finally give up on this issue and need help.
I configured my Nginx server to handle client authentication through certificate, that was simple:

First,
I used this tutorial to generate my client and server .crt
https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/

Then,
I added these lines into my configuration;

```
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myCA.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
```

Finally,
I installed the .pfx on my workstation, ran Internet explorer and browsed my website. IE asked me for the certificate and it worked fine!

After that, I decided to go with a real certificate, issued by a trusted company for obvious reasons. It's a **digicert sha2 secure server ca** by the way.

This time I converted the .pfx into .crt and .key, I uploaded the .crt into my Nginx server to replace myCa.crt then I added the pfx to my workstation.

Unfortunately, this time IE didn't want to prompt me for a certificate. I tried using Postman and I got this message (after adding the pfx into the settings/Certificates): **21:unable to verify the first certificate**

My question is, what is the difference between my trusted certificate and my self-generated? I can't figure out why this isn't working and I have no other error message to rely on.

For sure, I use the same trusted cert for both the client and the server, however I tried the same thing using my sefl-generated and it worked.

I have no clues...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you run `openssl x509 -text < your_digicert_certificate.crt` and report what's shown under "X509v3 Extended Key Usage"?

Comment: Hi @grawity , running it I got this, which sounds good: ```TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication``` I asked the provider, Digicert, and they told me that the intermediate certificate should be missing. But I don't know why/where it should be, within the crt file on within the trusted repository on both server/client..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after a long troubleshooting session I found out I have to add the Global root certificate into the trusted CA store of my Ubuntu server, and add all the chain certificate in the server side .crt file.

Thank you.